# Calculate RMSE for ARIMAX, using pyflux iu Python

Tags: python, time-series, metrics, mse

I am using `pyflux` and try to build an arimax model, using their [tutorial](https://pyflux.readthedocs.io/en/latest/arimax.html#).

I do not see any references in their documentation on how to calculate metrics (for example, RMSE). They only give AIC/BIC.

Any suggestions?